# how to write alternate lines in text file to another text file in python?

Tags: python

```
`import fileinput
f = open('file1', 'r')
f1 = open('file2', 'w')
f2 = open('file3', 'w')
i=0
for line in f:`
    if i==0:
        f1.write(line)
        i=1
    else:
        f2.write(line)
        i=0
f1.close()
f2.close()`
```

Trying with this code did not yield me any result.Also my files have text that is spread across multiple lines.So will this work ?

Comment: Didn't yield any result - meaning, no output of any kind and no files created?

Comment: No lines were copied @TigerhawkT3

Comment: Were the files created? If so, were they empty? If not, are you sure you're checking the correct directory? Was there any error message?

Comment: What do your tests say? What happens if you spread some `print` around the code e.g. print `line` after you entered the `for` loop.

Comment: It's not entering for loop @Matthias

Comment: Files are already present @TigerhawkT3

Comment: In that case `file1` is an empty file.

Comment: No it isn't.I rechecked it @Matthias

Comment: Worked for me once I fixed the syntax errors.

Comment: Assuming you remove the extraneous `` ` ``, and assuming a file called `file1` exists in the current working directory, and assuming you have proper permissions for all relevant locations, and assuming you're looking inside the correct directories, and assuming the input file actually has several lines... this should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all,for safety reasons, you must open your file using the [`with`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) keyword instead. Even you're not working on a a more important project with your actual code, it is good to have such good programming habits.

I propose you a simple approach to resolve your problem:

1. Read the file using [`readlines()`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html) method. This will result in a list where each line of your file represents an element of this list.

   `with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
      lines = f.readlines()`
2. Take advantage of `lines` list by rearranging into 2 separate lists the odd and even lines:

   `even_lines, odd_lines = lines[::2], lines[1::2]`
3. Loop on each sub-list to save its lines in the file of your choice:

   `with open('file1.txt','w') as f1:
      for odd_line in odd_lines:
          f1.write(odd_line)`

   `with open('file2.txt','w') as f2:
      for even_line in even_lines:
          f2.write(even_line)`

## Full program:

Let's just gather the above pieces of code into one small application:

```
# Safely open your file
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
   lines = f.readlines()

# Rearrange the lines according to the logic you are looking for
even_lines, odd_lines = lines[::2], lines[1::2]

# Safely open your files
with open('file1.txt','w') as f1:
   for odd_line in odd_lines:
       f1.write(odd_line)

with open('file2.txt','w') as f2:
   for even_line in even_lines:
       f2.write(even_line)
```

## Demo:

```
secuirty@begueradj:~/Desktop$ python tester.py 
security@begueradj:~/Desktop$ cat file1.txt
This is the line number 1
This is the line number 3
This is the line number 5
security@begueradj:~/Desktop$ cat file2.txt
This is the line number 0
This is the line number 2
This is the line number 4
hacker@begueradj:~/Desktop$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try,

```
text = f.readlines()

for line in text:
```

I assume you dont have " ' " signs in your original code.

Comment: Unnecessary and unhelpful.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Not gonna argue with you. Keerthimanu said it s not entering the loop. I dont know which version he is using but obviously it is about "in f" part. I believe code will work in this way.

Comment: File objects can be iterated over just fine. There's no reason that this suggestion should make the slightest difference (other than reducing performance, of course).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I got home and tried. You were right. (Y)

Answer (score -1):

Since file objects supports lazy iteration (effectively behaves as generators), I'll suggest using generator interface, namely [`next`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) function.

> Retrieve the next item from the iterator by calling its next() method. If default is given, it is returned if the iterator is exhausted, otherwise `StopIteration` is raised.

```
with open('file1', 'r') as src, open('file2', 'w') as dst_odd, open('file3', 'w') as dst_even:
    odd_line = next(src)
    dst_odd.write(odd_line)
    even_line = next(src)
    dst_even.write(even_line)
```

You'll also need to handle EOF - to do so, you may catch StopIteration exception.

```
with open('file1', 'r') as src, open('file2', 'w') as dst_odd, open('file3', 'w') as dst_even:
    try:
        odd_line = next(src)
    except StopIteration:
        pass  # stop processing - end of file
    dst_odd.write(odd_line)
    try:
        even_line = next(src)
    except StopIteration:
        pass  # stop processing - end of file
    dst_even.write(even_line)
```

To further reduce duplication in code and generalize case for arbitrary number of output files you may use something like:

```
import itertools
with open('file1', 'r') as src, open('file2', 'w') as dst_odd, open('file3', 'w') as dst_even:
    destinations = itertools.cycle([dst_odd, dst_even])  # additional file object may be passed here.
    try:
        next_line = next(src)
    except StopIteration:
        pass  # stop processing - end of file
    next_dst = next(destinations)
    next_dst.write(next_line)
```

Comment: Why isn't the OP's algorithm working, though? How does this actually help anything?